# What to do when mobile gets wet and the battery is not removable

Tags: hardware, htc-one-x, water-damage

I got my mobile (HTC One X) wet yesterday and I could not take out the battery since it is not removable.

Currently, everything works fine but I can see a dark blur shadow on the right of the screen and few dark spots all over the screen.

What should I supposed to do ? Do I need to take it to technician right away or I can stay calm ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your screen has been effected by the water and needs a new screen.

You can also [open it up](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/HTC+One+Teardown/13494/1%29) and dry the screen and digitalizer carefully. Maybe the screen and digitalizer are still wet on the inside. [iFixit](http://www.informationweek.com/mobility/smart-phones/htc-one-impossible-to-repair-says-ifixit/240151951) has said that it's "impossible" to repair it (open it up and being able to close it again), so be warned.

The other option is to turn your phone off and put it in the oven for a short few minutes. The heat will come into the phone and the water will dry up, but it's not guarenteed, since it looks like the screen has already been infected.


It's best to let a technician do it's thing. Take note that waterdamage is probably not a warranty thing, so that they're charging serious money. It's your choice to let it repair or not, because I don't think your phone will suddenly stop functioning. If it does, you can always let your phone being repaired later.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try the trick of sticking the phone in rice along with the things that Tom pointed out. But in the end, since you can already see the damage, it might already be too late. Seeing that you have a newer phone, you might still be under warranty, so I hate to say it but that probably will be your best bet if you want a completely fixed phone. Water damage is the worst to phones!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your warranty, budget and how much time you've got to invest in the fix...

- **Under Warranty**: If your phone is under warranty, contact the store you bought it from and find out if water damage is covered...If it is, you're golden! Let them fix it for free. Otherwise, read on...
- **Cheap, doesn't void warranty, but takes time**: Start with using a desiccant to try to dry-out the phone. This is the least invasive way to try to fix the problem as you don't have to take the phone apart, but as much water as it seems you've got in your phone...It could takes days to dry it out. If you've got rice around, then find some kind of container/tupperware that you can seal your phone in along with a bunch of rice. Then leave it sealed (important to seal it, so the rice is pulling the moisture from the phone and not the air) like that for several days. The other option, if you want something a little stronger than rice is to stop by an art&craft store and buy some desiccant bags. Do the same thing with sealing your phone in with the desiccant and leave for a couple of days and then check on it.
- **Cheap, but risky and could potentially void warranty**: Check the internet and sites like iFixit for directions on taking apart your phone. Do so and carefully dab dry any pools of wetness you find and then leave all the pieces out in the open air to dry overnight. Put it all back together the next day and the phone should be all better...And you'll have had the experience of taking apart a phone!
- **Safest, doesn't void warranty, but likely expensive**: Bring the phone to an authorized repair store and have them fix it. If the warranty doesn't cover it, it'll likely cost quite a bit but since it's done by an authorized repair shop, you won't lose warranty status in case something else happens.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped my HTC m9+ in the toilet and it was completely drowned. There was water inside the display within seconds.

I tried turning it off asap but it kept 
turning back on automatically 2 or 3 times because it was getting short circuited internally. After a few tries it turned off.

I took out the sim and sd card and placed the phone in a box of raw rice. After 6 days i plugged it back on into charging (in a wall socket) and the phone turned back on perfectly alhamdulillah. Its been more than a month, there is some problem with the sim tray though. The rest is working perfectly alhamdulillah.