# Phone screen went black after getting wet and will not turn on

Tags: troubleshooting, water-damage

My phone got wet in the rain, and the screen went black and will not turn on. I left it alone for 2 hours but to no avail. Now I'm charging the phone and it still wont work, the phone just vibrates every 3 seconds. I took out battery and put it back in, but that did not help. What do I do?

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, but the answers on [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24436/my-android-device-has-been-splashed-soaked-by-sea-water) should help you out.

Comment: Dont charge the phone right now! You'll fry it!

Comment: Most of the advice I've seen for a drenched phone (of any stripe) is to immediately turn it off, remove the battery, bury it in some uncooked rice for several days, and pray. If, after three or four days, if it won't take a charge or turn on, it's time for a new phone.