# Accidentally spill iced water on galaxy note 3 neo

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3, water-damage

I spill water on my galaxy note 3 neo. I then remove the original flip cover and wiped the water. It turns out that the water doesnt go through too far in the battery area.

My main concern that the water go through inside the home button.

What should I do after I wiped all the visible water?

Comment: @RossC I don't think this is quite the same as that. The advice to soak the computer is specific to a seawater dunking, for example.

Comment: @DanHulme Ignore the flag. I'll remove the comment, some of the more general advice in the [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24436/my-android-device-has-been-splashed-soaked-by-sea-water) might be useful to others so I'll leave this comment here, and delete the previous one. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best advice would be to remove all phone covers and leave in a well aired place to dry.

Also look at [this](http://m.wikihow.com/Save-a-Wet-Cell-Phone) it contains some useful advice

Comment: Can also put your phone in a bag of dried rice overnight, rice will absorb any moisture

Comment: I'd second the rice, works very well. Whatever you do, DO NOT APPLY ANY POWER TO THE DEVICE FIRST. That will definitely short it out.

Comment: @RossC Very true, unless you're 100℅ sure it's dry leave it off!

Comment: And don't feel tempted using a dryer, heat, or even a microwave! Neither is direct exposure to sun a good idea (heat factor again). The "rice pot" is the most often recommended method indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vacuum cleaner to remove water. Then pack it in plastic bag and keep in rice for 3 days