# water damaged Tmobile Revvl

Tags: water-damage

I dropped my android in the toilet last Thursday November 9, 2017 and it turned off and it kept going to the powered by android screen, on and off. It came back on that Saturday and I have been using it since with no problems. Today I got to work and was talking to my sister on it and it turned back off and has been doing the same thing it did the day I dropped it in the toilet with the exception of it will turn completely back on, but when I go to text someone or do anything with it, it turns right back off.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My android device has been splashed/soaked by sea water](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24436/my-android-device-has-been-splashed-soaked-by-sea-water)

Comment: My apologies, How can I fix it? What might possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

## You have to take it to a repair shop that has an ultrasonic cleaner.

You can't put it in rice or any other ridiculous mythical magical fix.

There is one option for you. ultrasonic cleaner.

## Why does rice and those other methods not work?

[CLICK HERE FOR CITATION](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Don%27t_Put_Your_Device_in_Rice._Here%27s_Why...)

Water is not harmful to electronics, it's the impurities in the water that hurt the electronics and cause corrosion.

Tell me what rice is going to do? Nothing. Don't use rice. Don't buy kits at the 95cent store. Don't do anything you read online. Don't follow YouTube videos. It's all fake stupid advice that doesn't work and can cause more harm than good.

If you don't have access to a repair shop and you just want to try to fix it yourself you can try to take apart the whole phone. Get to the circuit board and painstakingly clean every single part of the phone with high grade alcohol and a toothbrush. This is not as effective as an ultrasonic cleaner.

Also keep in mind an ultrasonic cleaner is not a guarantee. Water damage is the worst possible thing you could do to your phone. You are 99% screwed. Even if you take it to a repair shop keep in mind they will have NO GUARANTEE for water damage. That means that if they don't feel like cleaning it they don't have to. They can just take your money and do nothing because there is no guarantee with water damage. Even if they clean and fix it afterwards the problem could come back. BE CAREFUL PICKING YOUR REPAIR SHOP. GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Keep in mind that ultrasonic cleaner can help only if oxidation get small part of hardware.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје what do you mean?

Comment: Look on components under microscope if a lot of components are white than ultrasonic cleaner can't do much.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Oh right I agree! That's what I meant by "Also keep in mind an ultrasonic cleaner is not a guarantee." I figured the average person wouldn't have access to a microscope.

Comment: Ooh sorry I was too lazy to read whole question so I just commented

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Well anyone with a microscope will appreciate your comment :D