# What are my options to recover data from my water damaged phone?

Tags: internal-storage, recovery-mode, data-recovery, water-damage

My phone(Wileyfox Spark+, rooted and on COS 13, TWRP recovery) fell into water, and i got it out a few seconds later. I immediately took out the battery, sd card, sim, and lid, and left them in the sun to dry for two days. The SD cars is still functioning perfectly, the battery seems to be completely dead though.

These are my observations:

With another battery from an Samsung S Advance, this is what happens when I try to turn on the phone:
Buzz, light gray screen for a few seconds, then the screen turns off and stays off

When connecting the phone to a PC:
Windows connect sound, a few secs, disconnect sound, screen turns gray, then black, then gray, connect sound, black screen, then the charge indicator turns red/yellow. Disconnect sound when removing the battery again.
Windows says it doesn't recognise the USB device.

I'm not sure what happens, the screen turns gray now and then, but with a wavy pattern flowing over it. I don't think it'll be able to display anything useful anymore. It doesn't seem to be stuck in a bootloop, but i can't see if i can get into recovery mode.

EDIT: The phone is working with the original battery now when keeping it plugged to power. Both windows and the phone make a sound acknowledging that they're connecting and disconnecting when I plug or unplug the usb cable. The phone also reacts when i'm pressing the power button by lighting and dimming the screen, still in gray. The device is showed as a phone/music plater in win explorer, but no folders or files show up upon opening it. I didn't have a lock code or pattern on the phone.

What are my options to retrieve data from the interal storage? Is there a possibility/programs to access and recover it?

Comment: Qualified technical intervention is recommended. Unless it's hardware is inspected and found working you can't be sure of any method working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My android device has been splashed/soaked by sea water](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24436/my-android-device-has-been-splashed-soaked-by-sea-water)

Comment: @beeshyams That may be the most effective option, but i'd like to know if i can attempt to retrieve data myself. I've found a few programs that offer that service, but unfortunately only for samsungs. I was hoping that i could access the phone via the download or recovery mode.

Comment: Does `adb` work?

Comment: @confetti I think so, i did enable it once and trusted my pc. Usb debugging should also be enabled. The lockscreen can be unlocked with a swipe, so i think the usb connection just doesnt work. Or is there something else that must be done on the phone to make adb work?

Comment: As long as it's enabled and the phone unlocked it should work. There's probably too much damage if `adb devices` doesn't report anything.