# Dropped cell phone in water.display is working but touch is not responsive

Tags: screen, sony-xperia, water-damage

I accidentally dropped my Sony Xperia XA2 in water. I quickly picked the phone switched it off and tried to dry by using hair dryer for few seconds. Then wiped it with a cloth.
After which I accidentally switched on the phone and went to sleep.
When I woke up after 5 hours.only to check that my phone display is Working fine however the touch is not responsive.
Now I kept it in rice.Will my phone work fine or should I have to take it to expertise. As I am from India and this is imported phone.I am not sure if authorised service center will help me.
Thanks in advance,
Zack.

Comment: I don't think the hair dryer was a good idea. Usually they use a temperature way too high, which means that you may have damaged something. Also you should read [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186473/2241).

Comment: Thank you for the answer Robert. After 1+ days I switched it on. Luckily its working. Right now typing this from my phone. However, do I still need to take this to authorised service centre. Or is it fine to use it as it is now?