# Huawei Y6 Elite - Wet, Can Charge But Not Booting

Tags: huawei, water-damage, physical-damage

(If this is the wrong place to ask this question please tell me.)

I am in a bit of pickle right now.

It was quite rainy where I live, so when I took my phone (Huawei Y6 Elite Android 5.1) outside it fell in some water. It worked initially - I dried it and all.

Then, at the end of the day I powered it off.

I was trying to watch some YouTube, but then I couldn't power it on. I am 15 years old, and **my dad gave me the phone (which used to be his) so I just said I'm going to charge it to him so he wouldn't be suspicious.**

OK, so GOOD NEWS incoming.

Whenever I charge it, it shows up with the 'charging' screen.

I tried charging it for 1 hour and it wouldn't boot although it would show the charging screen.

Tried to put it in a bowl of rice for 1.6 days - took it out and still nothing.

I'm panicking right now as my dad would absolutely **kill** me if he finds out what I did to my phone, I need help ASAP.

Some of my ideas is to try to charge it for some more time and pray to G-d that it boots.

Another idea would be to tinker inside the components and dry them.

I need other ideas immediately. I am quite worried.

Thank you StackExchange - you have helped me with many issues at StackOverflow and I'm sure you can help a good friend out with this too.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked umpteen times on this site. Sorry to say but the only sensible solution is to let the service center deal with it and yes [rice does not help](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186473/131553)

Comment: @beeshyams you're right. Time to tell my dad and face the wrath.