# how to remove moist on the camera in my phone?

Tags: camera, water-damage, samsung-galaxy-s-21

I've managed to fall into the lake three times last week. 
Yes, I'm trying to learn to sail a [Laser dinghy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_(dinghy))

The cameras on my Samsung S21 Ultra now contains small droplets, and cannot take proper photos.

**How** do I get the **moist** to go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put it in an air-tight sealed box with some silicia gel. If this is not available, rice is also working fine. Let it sit for a couple of days and check it. If the water is still there, look for a possible repair shop.

Comment: [Rice doesn't work](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186473/131553)